# XAML does not make references to images

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

Im creating a page in XAML and I have a ImageSourece in my resources, like that:

```
<ImageSource x:Key="scale">imgs/gradient1px.png</ImageSource>
```

The files is in the correct folder, no spelling problems (I guess) and the Build action set to Resource.
The funnier think is that I have other picture with the same properties and it works!

The error message (on design time, the error appears on hovering) is:

```
The file is not part of the project or the Build Action is not set to Resource.
```

Here is an snapshot with the whole thing:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13848794/snapshot.png

Comment: Have you tried building your project?

Comment: yes I did, and clean and rebuild. Nothing changed

Comment: Try open [your_project]->Properties->Resources (select Images) and make sure that these images are all included there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget that .. the problem is that the XAML being edited was in a different project. No way for you to notice in the picture.
My bad.

If you tell me how to erase this question from the webiste.. I guess is not gonna be useful for anyone.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to delete the picture from your project, cleaning the solution and then re-adding it after.  Make sure you set your build action and build before adding it back to the xaml.

Comment: I did, same behavior. I commented the reference. I excluded from project the image. Cleaned, Build. That's Ok.
I added the existing item (file), check that the build action was properly set to Resource (it was), Build again (just in case), uncomment the resource reference and .. Same thing. The file does not exists or its build action is not set to resource.